# C# equivalent of OBJ-C's

Tags: c#, objective-c, arrays

Im converting an OBJ-C application to C# and am having trouble with this one:

What is the C# way to do this:

```
NSArray *charts = [xmlString componentsSeparatedByString:@"</record>"];
```

Comment: I don't know Objective C - can you explain what this line of code does?

Comment: it takes a string and converts it to an array of strings using "</record>" as a seperator... "bla bla bla </record> yo yo yo" would be turned into an array with the following objects: "bla bla bla" and "yo yo yo"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string[] charts = xmlString.Split(new string[] { "</record>" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: +1. As a minor detail, I *think* an `NSArray` is closer to a `List<T>` rather than a `T[]`. Might be wrong about that.

Comment: @Brodie: Do you actually have valid XML to start with? As I said in my answer, I would *strongly* urge you to reconsider using straight string operations if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

I misread the original question (or rather, comment) but I would *strongly* recommend that if you have some XML, you don't just split it by tag names - you parse it as XML, and then work with the parsed document. That will be much more reliable than using plain string operations.

For example, if you want to get the text within each `<record>` element you might use:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(text);
List<string> records = doc.Descendants("record")
                          .Select(x => x.Value)
                          .ToList();
```

Treating XML as a plain string is almost *always* a bad idea.

Comment: @JeremyP: It was downvoted because the original version of it suggested the use of `string.Join` - because I'd misread the OP's comment.